# Random.randrange method comes up with 0 all the time

Tags: python, random

I am having some trouble with my program. It randomly generates attributes depending on their chosen character.

Code:

```
import random

not_e =     {"Bulbasaur": ["Overgrow", "Tackle", "Leech Seed"],
                  "Charmander": ["Blaze", "Scratchy", "Growl"],
                  "Squirtle": ["Torrent", "Tackle", "Tail Whip"],
                  "Pikachu": ["Static", "Tail Whip", "Thunder Shock"],
                  "Haunter": ["Levitate", "Hypnosis", "Spite"],}

evolved = {"Venusaur": ["Overgrow", "Vine Whip", "Tackle", "Growl", "Poison Powder"],
                   "Charizard": ["Blaze", "Growl", "Ember", "Dragon Rage", "Dragon Claw"],
                   "Blastoise": ["Torrent", "Tackle", "Water Gun", "Withdraw", "Bite"],
                   "Raichu": ["Static", "Thunderbolt", "Quick Attack", "Thunder Shock", "Electro Ball"],
                   "Gengar": ["Levitate", "Hypnosis", "Spite", "Curse", "Night Shade"]}



class YourPokemon(object):
    name = ""
    hp = 0 #health points
    power = 0 # the pokemons power
    wwyd = ["FIGHT", "CHANGE POKEMON", "OPEN BAG", "RUN"]
    pokemon_type = ""
    not_e_powers = []

    def getRandomPokemon_Powers(self):
        name = random.choice(list(not_e.keys())) # gets random pokemon
        not_e_powers = not_e[name] # gets list of powers from randomly selected pokemon
        print("Your pokemon is: " + name + "! And it's powers are: " + str(not_e_powers))
        return name, not_e_powers;

    def healthPointsAndPower(self):
        r = random.randrange
        if self.name == "Bulbasaur":
            self.hp = r(45,50)
            self.power = r(40,45)
            self.pokemon_type = "Grass"
        elif self.name == "Charmander":
            self.hp = r(35,40)
            self.power = (45,50)
            self.pokemon_type = "Fire"
        elif self.name == "Squirtle":
            self.hp = r(40,45)
            self.power = (45,50)
            self.pokemon_type = "Water"
        elif self.name == "Pikachu":
            self.hp = r(30,35)
            self.power = r(45,50)
            self.pokemon_type = "Electric"
        elif self.name == "Haunter":
            self.hp = r(40,45)
            self.power = r(45,50)
            self.pokemon_type = "Ghost"

        print("Your pokemons Health Points and Power Points are: ", self.hp, " and ", self.power, "!")





your_character = YourPokemon()

your_character.getRandomPokemon_Powers()
your_character.healthPointsAndPower()
```

Updated code with r = random.randrange inside healthPointsAndPower method.

When I run it several times, it just prints out that the points generated are 0. All the time.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: i cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with just this code. Your problem must be lying somewhere else.  Is `r` redefined somewhere?

Comment: I have updated it. And I don't redefine R anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Your `self.name` is always empty, so none of the `if` tests match. `random.randrange` is never called, and `self.hp` and `self.power` remain at their class default value of `0`.

`self.name` is empty because your `getRandomPokemon_Powers` method never sets it:

```
name = random.choice(list(not_e.keys())) # gets random pokemon
```

sets a *local* variable `name`, not `self.name`. Change that function to:

```
def getRandomPokemon_Powers(self):
    self.name = random.choice(list(not_e.keys())) # gets random pokemon
    self.not_e_powers = not_e[name] # gets list of powers from randomly selected pokemon
    print("Your pokemon is: " + self.name + "! And it's powers are: " + str(self.not_e_powers))
    return self.name, self.not_e_powers
```

or set the `name` attribute on the instance somewhere else:

```
>>> your_character.name = 'Bulbasaur'
>>> your_character.not_e_powers = ['Overgrow', 'Tackle', 'Leech Seed']
>>> your_character.healthPointsAndPower()
('Your pokemons Health Points and Power Points are: ', 48, ' and ', 40, '!')
```

Comment: Yes, Python, unlike many other OO languages, does not have an implicit `this` or `self`. "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: @PaulDraper: The OP just forgot; other methods do use `self` correctly.

Comment: Maybe. `not_e_powers` is either purposefully unused, or not used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just print `random.randrange` in your main program and then in the method print `r` and that will tell you whether they are the same thing or not?

Even with the slightly sketchy information available it seem unlikely that you are calling `random.randrange()`. This test will verify the hypothesis, and then you can start looking for where `r` is bound to something else. Until you know what you are looking for you can look all you like without much hope of a postive result.

If it turns out they ARE the same then we'll need to see rather more of your code.

One final thing on really related to your question: as your skill develops you will start to realize that it isn't always best to just crank out code, since a little thought can save you a lot of typing and reduce your program size, making it easier to read (by experienced programmers). Here's some (untested) code to get you thinking.

```
pokemons = {
    "Bulbasaur": (45, 50, 40, 45, "Grass"),
    "Charmander": (35, 40, 45, 50, "Fire"),
    "Squirtle": (40, 45, 45, 50, "Water"),
    "Pikachu": (30, 35, 45, 50, "Electric"),
    "Haunter": (40, 45, 45, 50, "Ghost")
}
...

def healthPointsAndPower(self):
    hp_lo, hp_hi, pow_lo, pow_hi, ptype = pokemons[self.name]
    sef.hp = r(hp_lo, hp_hi)
    self.power = r(pow_lo, pow_hi)
    self.pokemon_type = ptype
```

**EDIT**: Either the question was edited or there was more code than I saw in formulating my answer.

Comment: A further advantage of my suggested alternative code, by the way, is that it would under these circumstances have raise a `Keyerror` exception. Of course the real answer is "never omit the `else` after a sequence of `elif`s if you always want action taken.

Comment: Yet your mapping technique would have caught the actual error perfectly.

Comment: (And sorry for the edit again, that missing quote was bugging me. :-))

Comment: I have no problem with other people editing errors out of my work - thanks!